# Is there a way to use a loop to perform an onclick function on multiple images?

Tags: javascript

So I have three images and on clicking anyone of them should perform the same function, I would like to implement a function that reduces the length of my code at the moment. Here's an example of the codebase:

Js code:

```js
    let doorImage1 = document.getElementById('door1')
    let doorImage2 = document.getElementById('door2')
    let doorImage3 = document.getElementById('door3')

    const botDoorPath = "new-url"

    doorImage1.onclick = () => {
      doorImage1.src = botDoorPath
    }

    doorImage2.onclick = () => {
      doorImage2.src = botDoorPath
    }

    doorImage3.onclick = () => {
      doorImage3.src = botDoorPath
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your code a bit, you can add a class to each image element, let's call it `door`, after doing this select all elements with that class and loop through it to apply the `onclick` function.

```js
let doorImages = document.querySelectorAll('.door')

const botDoorPath = "new-url"

for (let i = 0; i < doorImages.length; i++){
  let anImage = doorImages[i]
  anImage.onclick = () => (
      anImage.src = botDoorPath
      )

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also do:

```js
const botDoorPath = "new-url"

document.querySelectorAll('#door1, #door2, #door3' )
          .forEach(imgElm=>{
            imgElm.onclick=()=>
              {
              console.clear() 
              console.log('img clicked =', imgElm.id )
              imgElm.src = botDoorPath
              }
          })
```

```html
<img id="door1" src="xxxx">
<img id="door2" src="yyyy">
<img id="door3" src="zzzz">
```

Comment: ya this actually answers the questions because there are various reasons for not using class..

Comment: @bluejayke I think so too, otherwise I would have presented a solution with an event delegation ...

Answer (score 1):

You could do onclick with `class` instead of `id`

```js
let doorImage = document.querySelectorAll('.doors') //select all the elem that name of doors
const botDoorPath = "new-url"

doorImage.forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener('click', () => { //loop the elem and assign the click event
  elem.src = botDoorPath;
  console.log(elem)
}))
```

```html
<img class="doors" id="1" src="3">
<img class="doors" id="2"  src="3">
<img class="doors" id="3"  src="3">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through an array of all the images and perform the action:

```
let doorImages = document.querySelectorAll('.door')

const botDoorPath = "new-url"

for (let i = 0; i < doorImages.length; i++){
  let image = doorImages[i]
  image.addEventListener('click', () => {
  image.src = botDoorPath
  console.clear()
  console.log(image)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query for all images and loop through them

```js
let doorImgs = document.querySelectorAll('img')
const botDoorPath = "new-url"

doorImgs.forEach(image => image.addEventListener('click', () => { 
  image.src = botDoorPath;
  console.log(image)
}))
```

```html
<img src="1">
<img src="2">
<img src="3">
```